# Hibernate how to override entity without mapping superclass

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a set of entities in one common project and I want to override some values in subprojects. It can be different mapping, extra fields, etc...

When I add an entity that extends common's entity, it's created as subclass and requires discrimantor column.

In commons:

```
@Entity
class SomeTable {
  private Long id;
}
```

In subproject

```
@Entity
class SomeTable extends common.SomeTable {
    private String extraField;
}
```

What I basically want is to map the child entity (SubEntity) as org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass. I explicitly deleted common's class from PersistenceUnitInfo with org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitPostProcessor, but it doesn't help. Is there a way to forbid mapping the parent class?

I'm working with spring-boot and Hibernate 5.0.11

**Upd:** So far I came up with a solution to map both SomeTable entities with xml config and delete them from PersistenceUnitInfo. Not very nice approach as per my opinion but it allows to do what I wanted to do: to keep all common code of few projects separately and be able to override some models in subprojects...

Answer (score 0):

Add `@javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass` annotation instead of `@javax.persistence.Entity` on your `SomeTable` class.

This was your `SomeTable` class will not be mapped or create any additional tables. It will only add extra columns to other entities which inherit from it.

Comment: I tried this approach. The problem is that comon.SomeTable is referenced by other Entities in the commons.
So I get errors that other entities reference unmapped class.